# create HTML list in C# based on DB values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, email, sendgrid

I am working on sending out order confirmations on a web site with a shop functionality - all pretty much custom designed. I would like an email to be sent out once the order has been placed, **ideally with a brief summary/overview of the ordered items**.
I have managed to get to the point where the submission of the order triggers an email to be sent to the user, so that is all good. However, **my question is how can I customize the email body in a way so it would include the list of ordered items?**

Happy to add code from my controller, although I don't really think this is adding much value as this is more of a **how-to-question** rather than an issue I am encountering.

```
int orderID = order.ID;
var lineItems = DATADB.LineItemList.Where(x => x.OrderNumber == 0 && x.UserID == userID);
lineItems.ForEach(l => l.OrderNumber = orderID);
DATADB.SaveChanges();

// send order confirmation email
var orderConfirmation = DATADB.LineItemList.Where(x => x.OrderNumber == orderID).ToList();
var ordered = string.Join(",", lineItems);
var msg = new SendGridMessage();
msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("orders@freshNclean.ch", "freshNclean");
msg.AddTo(UserManager.FindById(userID).Email);
msg.Subject = "Deine Bestellung bei freshNclean";

msg.Text = "Hi " + UserManager.FindById(userID).FirstName.ToString() + "! Vielen Dank für Deine Bestellung." + ordered;

// SendGrid credentials
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SGaccount"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SGpassword"]);
var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
if (transportWeb != null)
{
    transportWeb.DeliverAsync(msg);
}
else
{
    Trace.TraceError("Web Transport konnte nicht generiert werden - die Nachricht wurde nicht versandt.");
    Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Essentially, the question is **how do I get from**...

```
var orderConfirmation = DATADB.LineItemList.Where(x => x.OrderNumber == orderID).ToList();
```

**... to the actual rows and values within these rows, so I can include them in the email body?** Also, once that is established, how will I get the body of the email to include a list or a table that gives an acceptable look and feel to the order confirmation?

Comment: A super basic approach would be to loop over the orderConfirmations (make sure you pluralize your variable name if it represents a collection)  and append each order as a string to the email body. Longer term, you may want to think about using a templating engine, such as Razor, which has specialized email libraries such as [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/).

Comment: Thx @mason.. Would you mind providing an example (code)

Comment: Provide what code? The first thing I described was pretty short....you know how to loop over objects in a collection, create strings, and append them to other strings, right? And for the templating engine example, I provided a link to a specific library that includes their own examples.

Comment: @mason the thing is i really don't know how to loop...

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to spend some time looking at basic tutorials. They'll cover for loops, foreach loops, and while loops. Stack Overflow isn't a good tool for teaching you the very basics of a language. It's assumed that you at least have some foundation for the language basics when you post here.